# Using VP8.NET to stream to a webm file

Tags: c#, video, video-streaming, webm, vp8

I am using the [VP8 .NET](http://vp8.codeplex.com/) library to convert a video stream from my laptop webcam and i would like to store it in a webm file (no audio needed). To do so, I'm using the code provided as example in the documentation of the library and I added a few lines of code to write the encoded stream to a file. Here's the code:

```
class EncodingSession
{
    private readonly VP8.Encoder Encoder;
    static FileStream fs = new FileStream("provavideo.webm", FileMode.CreateNew);
    BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(fs);

    public EncodingSession(int width, int height, int fps)
    {
        Encoder = new VP8.Encoder(width, height, fps);

    }

    public byte[] Encode(Image frame)
    {
        Encoder.ForceKeyframe();
        byte[] array = Encoder.Encode((Bitmap)frame);
        w.Write(array);
        return array;
    }

}
```

However, this does not produce a valid webm file, probably because the webm headers are missing. My question is: how do I add a valid webm header (if this is really what is needed)? Are there other stuff needed to be added to my file?

Comment: Have you ever figured this out?

Comment: link broken is there an alternative

Comment: I just want to point out why it doesn't work, because webm is a container format and VP8 is a codec, so it's missing some information about timings the codec that is used the streams and many more things that are required by the containers.